# IBM Maximo Document Attachment not working

Tags: websphere, maximo, ibm-maximo-worker-insights

We have move the IBM Maximo application and database on cloud server. Users attached documents with contract, PO,PR etc. When users click on attachement to view it this error appears.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Attached document is submitted on server DOCLINK folder of server successfully.
Folder management, doclink folder sharing and other configuration (httpd file document root) are made as per IBM Maximo atricle. Restarted websphere after live refreshed but...

Kindly help me to sort out this issue.